# How to fix hard lockups (mentioning some IRQ) in my Eeepc laptop (running Linux)?

Tags: linux, freeze, irq

My EeePC 1015PEM tends to block sometimes (approximately once per 2 days). Even `_` cursor in (modesetted) text mode does not blink. After rebooting (unless battery and adaptor was removed) it shows the following messages from kernel (approximately 10 seconds after kernel boot):

```
[    9.166462] irq 19: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[    9.172089] Pid: 0, comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.2.0-zen-vi+ #5
[    9.176398] Call Trace:
[    9.176398]  [<c017c2e2>] __report_bad_irq+0x2e/0xb9
[    9.176398]  [<c017c4a9>] note_interrupt+0x13c/0x1b1
[    9.176398]  [<c017a925>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x15d/0x173
[    9.176398]  [<c011e7f0>] ? native_irq_disable+0x8/0xb
[    9.176398]  [<c017cb02>] ? handle_edge_irq+0xd0/0xd0
[    9.176398]  [<c017a964>] handle_irq_event+0x29/0x40
[    9.176398]  [<c017cb02>] ? handle_edge_irq+0xd0/0xd0
[    9.176398]  [<c017cb70>] handle_fasteoi_irq+0x6e/0x87
[    9.176398]  <IRQ>  [<c0103504>] ? do_IRQ+0x3c/0xa0
[    9.176398]  [<c0156a3c>] ? __hrtimer_start_range_ns+0x31d/0x328
[    9.176398]  [<c050bbb0>] ? common_interrupt+0x30/0x38
[    9.176398]  [<c01300e0>] ? init_cfs_bandwidth+0x6f/0x8f
[    9.176398]  [<c032f5e7>] ? intel_idle+0xbc/0xef
[    9.176398]  [<c044a767>] ? cpuidle_idle_call+0xda/0x17e
[    9.176398]  [<c0101cb0>] ? cpu_idle+0x9a/0xbe
[    9.176398]  [<c04edd99>] ? rest_init+0x5d/0x5f
[    9.176398]  [<c074c80c>] ? start_kernel+0x329/0x32f
[    9.176398]  [<c074c31b>] ? kernel_init+0x11b/0x11b
[    9.176398]  [<c074c0b2>] ? i386_start_kernel+0xb2/0xba
[    9.176398] handlers:
[    9.176398] [<c041dbef>] usb_hcd_irq
[    9.176398] Disabling IRQ #19
```

I tried kernels from about 2.6.37 to 3.3. "irqpoll" option is already present in kernel command line. What can I do to fix/investigate the problem.

```
# cat /proc/interrupts # Note: this time it booted without that "nobody cared" message.
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:    4688875    4699663    4662934    4675216   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:      15329      15149      15170      15196   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  8:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:     231057     230593     231830     232090   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:      24351      24190      24367      24514   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:      36252      36645      37945      37750   IO-APIC-fasteoi   i915, uhci_hcd:usb4
 17:     518208     521323     518341     517988   IO-APIC-fasteoi   brcmsmac
 18:         38         38         42         39   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb3
 19:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb2
 21:     164238     163330     162665     163105   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ahci
 22:      33584      33242      33372      33355   IO-APIC-fasteoi   snd_hda_intel
 23:        375        343        357        385   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb1, ehci_hcd:usb5
NMI:          1          1          1          1   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:    7749050    7005979    7071719    7162365   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          0          0          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:    2127760    1548108    1081554    1201221   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:     134734     133266        204        217   Function call interrupts
TLB:      11475       7914      21647      25712   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:        533        533        533        533   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
```

```
# lspci -vv
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation N10 Family DMI Bridge (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ac
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ac
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at f7e00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Region 1: I/O ports at dc00 [size=8]
    Region 2: Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 3: Memory at f7d00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ac
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Region 0: Memory at f7e80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 841c
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 22
    Region 0: Memory at f7cf8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v1) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
            ExtTag- RBE- FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed unknown, Width x0, ASPM unknown, Latency L0 <64ns, L1 <1us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed unknown, Width x0, TrErr- Train- SlotClk- DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=1 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=80
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [130 v1] Root Complex Link
        Desc:   PortNumber=0f ComponentID=00 EltType=Config
        Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=00 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
            Addr:   00000000fed1c000
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: 80200000-803fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080400000-00000000805fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: [40] Express (v1) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- RBE- FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <1us, L1 <4us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x0, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+
            Slot #0, PowerLimit 0.000W; Interlock- NoCompl-
        SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
            Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
        SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet- Interlock-
            Changed: MRL- PresDet- LinkState-
        RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible-
        RootCap: CRSVisible-
        RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable- ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=00
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [180 v1] Root Complex Link
        Desc:   PortNumber=01 ComponentID=00 EltType=Config
        Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=00 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
            Addr:   00000000fed1c001
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00001000-00001fff
    Memory behind bridge: f8000000-fbffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f0000000-00000000f6ffffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: [40] Express (v1) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- RBE- FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #2, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <256ns, L1 <4us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+
            Slot #0, PowerLimit 0.000W; Interlock- NoCompl-
        SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
            Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
        SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet+ Interlock-
            Changed: MRL- PresDet+ LinkState+
        RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible-
        RootCap: CRSVisible-
        RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable- ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=00
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [180 v1] Root Complex Link
        Desc:   PortNumber=02 ComponentID=00 EltType=Config
        Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=00 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
            Addr:   00000000fed1c001
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f7f00000-f7ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000080000000-00000000801fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: [40] Express (v1) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- RBE- FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #4, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <256ns, L1 <4us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug+ Surprise+
            Slot #0, PowerLimit 0.000W; Interlock- NoCompl-
        SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
            Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
        SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet+ Interlock-
            Changed: MRL- PresDet+ LinkState+
        RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible-
        RootCap: CRSVisible-
        RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
        VC1:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed+ WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable- ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=00
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [180 v1] Root Complex Link
        Desc:   PortNumber=04 ComponentID=00 EltType=Config
        Link0:  Desc:   TargetPort=00 TargetComponent=00 AssocRCRB- LinkType=MemMapped LinkValid+
            Addr:   00000000fed1c001
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
    Region 4: I/O ports at d400 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 19
    Region 4: I/O ports at d480 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 18
    Region 4: I/O ports at d800 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin D routed to IRQ 16
    Region 4: I/O ports at d880 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 23
    Region 0: Memory at f7cf7c00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e2) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=05, sec-latency=32
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR+ NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: [50] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ad
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 21
    Region 0: I/O ports at d080 [size=8]
    Region 1: I/O ports at d000 [size=4]
    Region 2: I/O ports at cc00 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at c880 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at c800 [size=32]
    Region 5: Memory at f7cf7800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0 BAR4 Offset=00000004
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8132 Fast Ethernet (rev c0)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 838a
    Physical Slot: eeepc-wifi
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
    Region 0: Memory at f7fc0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at ec00 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [58] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 4096 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag- AttnBtn+ AttnInd+ PwrInd+ RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr+ FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [6c] Vital Product Data
        Not readable
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq+ ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP- SDES+ TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 14, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [180 v1] Device Serial Number ff-49-9f-3d-20-cf-30-ff
    Kernel driver in use: atl1c

02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2047
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at fbffc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=2 PME-
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [d0] Express (v1) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr+ UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq+ AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Latency L0 <4us, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 14, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [13c v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 00-00-6d-ff-ff-7e-74-f0
    Capabilities: [16c v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
pcilib: sysfs_read_vpd: read failed: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `cat /proc/interrupts` and `lspci -vv`? Also, check BIOS settings. Disable hardware you're not using and make sure to set the hard drive controller to AHCI.

Comment: BTW looks like the [netconsole](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-netconsole-log-management-tutorial.html) module is a charm against freezes: keeping the netbook [Ethernet-connected to laptop](http://superuser.com/questions/275474/why-touchpad-glitches-when-ethernet-cable-is-connected#comment462029_275474) for netconsole for 6 days - no freezes (it was approximately once per day before).